# MPMoviePlayerController seek bar is not appearing after applying natural size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` for playing video files and I am able to apply the natural size of the video with the help of `MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification`. But after adding this notification **seek bar is not appearing** in the controlStyle (all other buttons are present). If I make the video frame hard coded (i.e. without considering the natural height) I will not get this issue.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
// Declartion class level

     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;    
      float naturalHeight;


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   moviewPlayer  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieReadyForDisplay:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieNaturalSizeAvailable:)
                                                 name:MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

       [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;


    moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO; 

    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill; 

    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;



  //I am able to get the seek bar here if I set the static height . But I want natural height here.
   //  moviePlayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , naturalHeight);
}

-(void) movieNaturalSizeAvailable:(NSNotification *)notification{

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification object:player];

    naturalHeight = player.naturalSize.height;

    if(naturalHeight > self.view.frame.size.height) {
        naturalHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    }

}

-(void) movieReadyForDisplay:(NSNotification *)notification{

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification object:player];

    NSLog(@">> %f ", naturalHeight); //OK here

    [player view].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , naturalHeight);
    player.view.center = self.view.center;

    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

}


- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

    [player stop];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];

}


@end
```

I believe this issue might be because the natural size calculations of
video player occur after it sets its components frames. If I don't use natural size, it works perfectly. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please let me know .. any solution for the above issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce, please share more code.

Comment: moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

Answer (score 0):

try this

before starting the video

```
player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

and when movie starts playing then set

```
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

You can get play callback from MPMediaPlayback protocol.